# Strange average value of array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, return

I am learning C++ arrays. In code below:

```
double mean(int n, double *a)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
        return sum/n;
    }
}

main()
{
    double t[]={5, 5};
    cout << mean(2,t) << endl;
}
```

`mean` returns 2.5, although it should return as 5 as I think.

Does anyone know why 2.5 was returned from `mean`?

Comment: does the code even compile? doesn't it say the function does not return a value in all its branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will return the first element of the array divided by the number of elements. To fix it you can just move the `return sum / n` statement outside of the `for` loop:

```
double mean(int n, double *a){
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum/n;
}
```

But with the help of the standard library algorithm [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) you can simplify your code to:

```
inline double mean(int n, double *a) {
    return std::accumulate(a, a + n, 0) / n;
}
```

And [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7769a6149ebb9ca4)'s the working example.

Finally remember to avoid `using namespace std` and to always specify the return type of the `main` function. Also, turn on compiler warnings, as you [would have been warned](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2c30330eeae0ced) that something weird some happening in your code.

Answer (score 2):

`return sum/n;` needs to be outside the `for`.

Step through your code: after adding `a[0]` to `sum`, the function returns `sum/n`, which is `5/2`.